# How ticksize arguments are defined in d3 js when the orientation is top?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I was going through the following code. Here ticksize is passed a negative argument.  I was thinking that the positive argument should be okay but it is not since it should draw a line from the top. I want to know why? Is it due to some internal transformation which may have took place?

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("top")
.tickSize(-height - margin.bottom)
.tickFormat(format);
```

The code is the part of link: [Mike Bostocks' Object Constancy Explanation](https://github.com/mbostock/bost.ocks.org/blob/gh-pages/mike/constancy/index.html). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Things that have a negative scale in SVG are drawn upside down. Tick's are scaled in d3 so they work the same way so if you have a positive tickSize it draws outside the axis line and if it's negative it's drawn inside the line instead.

Comment: How is the scale negative?